# CSS display size is changed due to length of text

Tags: html, css, block

I want to make a formatted paragraph whose image is located in left, the text is located in right with CSS.

However, it looks good when I type a single line text, but the top position is changed when I type two-line text or more.

Its source is on 
http://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/1883/

and the main part of CSS is:

```
.post-container {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    border: 1px dotted #333;
    overflow: auto;
}
.greenbox {
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted #383;
    width: 100%;
}
.redbox {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted #f33;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
}
.redbox10 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted #f33;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And its HTML code is like:

```
<div class="greenbox">
    <div class="redbox10">
        <img src="#">
    </div>
    <div class="redbox">
        One Line Text
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I place the top line same whatever I type in?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the left column to align at the top.

```
.redbox10 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/RXrvZ/1886/)

[image: Align at the top]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify vertical align to be top:

```
.redbox, img{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's the updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/1884/)

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer. (clicking right arrow)

Answer (score 0):

you should use float:

```
.redbox {
    float: left;
}
.redbox10 {
    float: left;
}
```

[image: Demo]

you can give them a `margin` for some space.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/1887/)

[Demo With Margin](http://jsfiddle.net/RXrvZ/1889/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be rather simplified if made using a table.

I hope this helps.

```css
.mainTable{
    padding: 10px;
   
}

.outerRow{    
   padding: 10px;
}

.imageColumn{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.textColumn{
    border: 1px solid;
     padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">                
    <table class="mainTable">
        <tr class="outerRow">
            <td class="imageColumn">
                <img src="#"/>
            </td>
            <td class="textColumn">
                One Line Text
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="outerRow">
            <td class="imageColumn">
                <img src="#"/>
            </td>
            <td class="textColumn">
                Two Lines Text - rai oda bi iod ieo idooosido oiojs oijodif oijoa oijsdf
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="outerRow">
            <td class="imageColumn">
                <img src="#"/>
            </td>
            <td class="textColumn">
                Three Lines Text - rai oda bi iod ieo idooosido oiojs oijodif oijoa oijsdf hello hello hello hello hello hellohellohellohellohellohello
              
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </table> 
            </div>
```